# sending FFMPEG the start_number of image sequence in a batch script

Tags: windows, batch-file, ffmpeg

I'm creating a batch script to daily convert screen captures to video
Its all working except I cant get the screen caps to start at 0001 each day,so my current script fails.

Is there a way within FFMPEG to just read all the files in a folder (e.g. if I have one folder with 500 files starting with 01234.jpg and another folder with files starting at 87654.jpg)?

If not, can I use the batch script to find the start and finish points and send that to ffmpeg?

my script

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

rem Check if a new folder has been added to the watched folder
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('dir "Y:\fastone_timelapse" /B /AD') do (
   set "new_folder=%%a"

   rem Check if jpeg files are present in the new folder
   if exist "Y:\ft\!new_folder!\*.jpg" (
         
ffmpeg.exe -f image2 -framerate 25 -pattern_type sequence -start_number 00001 -i "Y:\ft\!new_folder!\%%05d.jpg" -c:v libx265 -b:v 5000k -g 100 "Y:\ft\!new_folder!.mp4"


   )
)
endlocal
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   if exist "Y:\ft\!new_folder!\*.jpg" (
    set "first="
    for /f %%y in ('dir /on /b /a-d "Y:\ft\!new_folder!\*.jpg"') do set "last=%%~ny"&if not defined first set "first=%%~ny"
    echo First=!first! Last=!last!
    ffmpeg.exe -f image2 -framerate 25 -pattern_type sequence -start_number 00001 -i "Y:\ft\!new_folder!\%%05d.jpg" -c:v libx265 -b:v 5000k -g 100 "Y:\ft\!new_folder!.mp4"
```

BTW, you don't appear to need `new_folder` as each appearance of `!new_folder!` can be replaced by `%%a`.